# How do you do an "href" link in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website currently use this:

```
for (var i = 1; i<25; i++){
$('#photos').append('<img src="Sections/Blondes/'+i+'.jpg">');
}
```

To display images, however when I do the same thing for "href":

```
$("#photos").append("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```

Here is my css for "#photos":

```
#photos img {
  width: 100% ;
  height: auto;
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1080px) {
#photos {
   line-height: 0;
   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}
#photos img {
  width: 100% ;
  height: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}
}
```

I am trying to add an lightbox to each image and for that to be done the href link is need.

The lightbox I'm using:

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

How can this be done?

Comment: This is not html; html doesn't have for loops.

Comment: `href` is an anchor element attribute.. but I've never seen it used in the way you are trying to.  Perhaps you are trying to set an attribute.. you can do that using the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

Comment: What does adding an `href` have to do with displaying an image? You're really not describing the problem you're ultimately trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attr if you want to add an href to an element.

```
 $("#photos").attr( "href", "http://www.google.com/" );
```

Comment: What type of element are you trying to assign an href to?

Comment: Added more details to my question.

Comment: Ahh, OK. So use the method I provided, but you need to target an anchor, not the image nor its container. Basically, you just need to wrap each <img> element with an <a> tag and then apply the attr to the <a> tag. Divs do not have an  href attribute which is why your append is not working while trying to append an href to it.

Answer (score 2):

In the example that is working, you put the entire image in the #photos. The href is a property of the link tag, so I think that you need to change this:

```
$("#photos").append("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```

To this:

```
$('#photos').append('<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>');
```

Comment: What is the #photos element? What error are you getting?